# Set field through a function

Tags: java

I am trying to make a generic method in that will set a field through a Function, like this :

```
public static <T> void setFieldValue(T model, Function<T,String> field){
    String name = "some name";
   //What to do here as well
    field.apply(model);
}
```

Let's say that I have an object from a class named Person, with a name field, and I want to set the object name through this method with lambda exprassion. How do I do so?

```
Person person = new Person();
setFieldValue(person, p-> //What to do here?);
```

And if it is not possible what is the recommended way to do it?

***Clarification***

The new value of the field will be decided inside the `setFieldValue`, I have edited my code

Comment: Works well. Why don't you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Function<T,String>` will definitely *not* work: it consumes a `T` and *returns* a `String`. You don't need a function that returns anything. You need one that takes a `T` and a `String` and puts one in the other.

So a `BiConsumer<T,String>` would fit your needs better:

```
public static <T> void setFieldValue(T model, BiConsumer<T,String> consumer){
    String name = "some name";

    consumer.accept(model,name);
}
```

Which you can then use as:

```
setFieldValue(p, (person,name) -> person.setName(name) );
```

This means you have a function that takes any person and name and gives that person that name, and it fits the `BiConsumer` requirements, so when you call `accept`, `model` will set the `person` and `name` will set the `name`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
public static <T> void set(T model, Consumer<T> consumer){
    consumor.accept(model);
}
```

Then you can set the name as follows:

```
Person p = new Person();
set(p, p2 -> p2.setName("test"));
```

**Edit:** User changed the question

Try BiConsumer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html

Comment: I have edited my question, I want to change the name inside the method

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
setFieldValue(person, (p) -> "");
```

(since the return type of your `Function` is `String`).

But if you don't need a return-type, however, changing `Function` to `Consumer` would make more sense:

```
public static <T> void set(T model, Consumer<T> consumor){
    consumor.accept(model);
}

set(person, p -> { //something that returns void });
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I want to change the name inside the method